# xcodeが文字を入力する度にコンパイルされて重すぎる

Tags: xcode

xcode8を使用しています。
大きめのプロジェクトを開発しているのですが、ソースコードの文字を一文字でも入力したり、削除したりする度にコンパイルが始まり、とても重くメソッド等の候補も出ない状態になります。

リアルタイムにコンパイルしてリアルタイムにエラーを表示するのは普通ですが、
私の場合上部のプログレスバーが動くようなコンパイルが始まり、その間１０秒程度メソッドの候補などが出なくなります。
（そもそも文字を入力しても数秒後に画面に反映されるなどとても重い状態になる時もあります。）
仮に１０秒待ったとしても文字を一文字でも操作する度にこの状態になるのでほぼ常にメソッド候補はでないです。

これの対処法はありますか？
キャッシュ・ログの削除は行っています。
スペック、メモリについても問題ありません。

Comment: ソースコードの編集が一段落するまで、自動コンパイルを無効にすれば良いのではないでしょうか？　変数名に１文字加えたり、１文字消したりしたら、普通コンパイルエラーが生じます。それを毎回リアルタイムに表示するのが「普通」とは思えません。

Comment: related? [Xcode keeps building storyboard after each keystroke - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28476030)

Comment: @Yosh それですね！よろしければ回答でお願いします。

Comment: @D.T お役に立てて嬉しいのですが，実は Xcode に触ったこともないので，お手数ですがよろしければご自身で回答を編集していただければ一番ありがたいです（信用度についてのご配慮等は不要です）．

Answer (score -2):

xcodeのウィンドウが一つだとこの現象は直りました。
例えば、２つめのウィンドウで　storyboard　などを開いているだけでこの現象になります。
（文字を入力する度にコンパイルされて何もできない）